# Using "Debit" as a verb

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I saw in various dictionaries that Debit has a verb definition.

Example from Dictionary.com:

> verb (used with object)
>
> 4. to charge with a debt: The store debited her account for the purchase.
> 5. to charge as a debt: The store debited the purchase to her account.

However, I couldn't find any example sentences which people actually used containing the verb form of debited.
I need do decide whether I want to use this word in our company documentation instead of "charge", for the sake of consistency.

For example:
Specify the item for which the customer is being debited.

**Also** - assuming the word can be used in this manner - is it OK to say that a person is being debited, or can only accounts be debited?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: As a verb, we normally talk of "debiting" an account in a ledger, i.e. in the firm's book-keeping system. Because not everyone is familiar with the meaning of the word (and double-entry book-keeping in general) we sometimes talk of 'charging' an account rather then "debiting" it.

Comment: @BillJ As someone who spent forty years in the accountancy profession let me agree with you, and add that *debit* and *credit* can each be used as noun, adjective and verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb ***[to debit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/debit)*** is generally used with  (bank) acconts:

​***to take money out of an account or keep a record of this:***

> - *The bank debited my account.*
> - *The bank debited the money from my account.*
> - *The unauthorized borrowing fee will be debited to your account.*

***To charge***  has the same meaning here:

> - *The bill was charged to my account*

To [charge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/charge?q=charge%20) (not debit)  is also used when you ask money for goods/services:

> - to ask an amount of money for something, especially a service or activity:
>
>   - *How much/What do you charge for a haircut and blow-dry?*
>   - *The bank charged commission to change my traveller's cheques.*
>   - *[ + two objects ] They charge you $20 just to get in the nightclub.
>       The local museum doesn't charge for admission.*

Coming to your sentence, "charge" is correct or you could say:

> ..the item for which the customer's account is being debited.

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

As someone who spent forty years in the accountancy profession let me explain that both *debit* and *credit* can each be used as verb, adjective or noun.

**Noun**

*For every **debit** there must be a corresponding **credit**.(fundamental law of bookkeeping.)

Or *a **credit** in the cash account is matched by a **debit**, elsewhere, e.g. in a customer account*.

**Adjective**

*The account contains a number of unexplained **debit/credit entries**.

or *In any set of books the sum of all the **debit balances** should equal the sum of all the **credit balances***.

**Verb**

*If you **debit** the customer's account, they will owe you more money*.

*By **crediting** the Profit & Loss a/c you increase the reported profit of the business*.

Comment: Chartered accountancy is rather exciting, isn't it?

Comment: @deadrat It can be as exciting as sky-diving! Depends whose accounts you are keeping.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azkFz1ZbXyU

Comment: @deadrat I watched that particular episode of Monty Python when it was first shown on late-night BBC. As I try to explain to my children, I didn't go to work to have fun, but to keep them in the things to which they were glad to be accustomed.

Comment: Children? I kept asking my accountant about them. He could never make the numbers work.